# understanding Multiplicity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

in my books of algebra it talks about polynomial functions and their zeros

> Multiplicity and x-Intercepts
>   If r is a zero of even multiplicity, then the graph touches the x-axis and turns
>   around at r. If r is a zero of odd multiplicity, then the graph crosses the x-axis
>   at r. Regardless of whether the multiplicity of a zero is even or odd, graphs tend
>   to flatten out near zeros with multiplicity greater than one.

what does flatten out means ?

Comment: Could you give us a little more context? What book is it, and what is the subject? The "zero" of what?

Comment: It means they don't grow very fast.  Graph $y=x^n$ for some different values of $n$ on Wolfram Alpha, to see what the book means.

Comment: zero of a polynomial function from book "Blitzer college algebra" Multiplicity and x-Intercepts
If r is a zero of even multiplicity, then the graph touches the xaxis and turns
around at r. If r is a zero of odd multiplicity, then the graph crosses the xaxis
at r. Regardless of whether the multiplicity of a zero is even or odd, graphs tend
to flatten out near zeros with multiplicity greater than one.

Comment: @AhmedM.Elsonbaty Compare for example the "flatness" of [$x, x^2, x^3, x^4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+,+x%5E2+,+x%5E3+,+x%5E4+for+-1.2+%3C+x+%3C+1.2) around $\,x=0\,$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the book is probably trying to convey is that when a polynomial has a repeated root, the slope of the function tends to approach zero when $y=0$. Take, for example, the graph of $y=\left(x+1\right)^3\left(x+3\right)$:

[image: Graph of Function]

The graph has a repeated root of $x=-1$ with a multipicity of 3. The slope of the graph approaches zero as $x$ approaches -1.

Comment: +1 for  a crisp answer. In your last sentence you mean "slope of the *tangent* to the graph" I suppose.